# BeautifulSoup4 returns None although the tag exists

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am following tutorial for Python3 and BeautifulSoup.
For the following code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html')
print(html.read())
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
print("\n\n-----H1 content after this-----")
print(bs.h1)
```

I get:

```
b'<html>\n<head>\n<title>A Useful Page</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h1>An Interesting Title</h1>\n<div>\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>\n'


-----H1 content after this-----
None
```

The `None` is unexpected as the h1 tag exists. I get exactly the same result for `print(bs.find("h1"))`
How can I get the contents of h1 tag?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.find("h1").text)


main("http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html")
```

Output:

```
An Interesting Title
```

Comment: Now I realised I've read to the end of the stream by invoking html.read() twice x.x

Comment: @Yoda that's it.